# sed bash replace ,, with ,

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with the following content:

```
 {
        "user_id1": "171295",
        "timeStamp": "2017-03-06 19:16:58.000"
    },,
    {
        "user_id1": "149821",
        "timeStamp": "2017-03-08 12:50:47.000"
    },,
    {
        "user_id1": "184767",
        "timeStamp": "2017-03-08 19:55:25.000"
    },,
    {
        "user_id1": "146364",
        "timeStamp": "2017-03-12 23:48:48.000"
    },
]
```

I want to replace all instances of `},,` with `},` in bash using `sed` how do I do this?

Comment: "using sed"? Not that it's a bad choice, but is there a reason you're setting up the question to preliminarily reject any answer that doesn't use that *particular* tool? (There are several cases -- particularly when processing a line at a time rather than a whole file -- when `sed` *is* the wrong tool for the job, which is why asking questions in such a way as to ensure that you'll only get answers conforming with preexisting expectations is unfortunate).

Comment: You have what appears to be JSON that has been rendered syntactically invalid by the addition of extra commas; this fact suggests to me that you may have been manipulating data using an inappropriate tool to begin with. Might I suggest that if you are going to be dealing with JSON, you use a tool or library explicitly designed for it? From the shell, I recommend [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: (That comment was for future reference; JSON tools won't help you with this problem, since the text you're working with is not yet/anymore valid JSON.)

Comment: What's wrong with "using sed"? You are lucky if you have `sed` :) What if you need to do it in `busybox`? Confinement with environment and tools is part of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/},,/},/g' < in > out
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the many ways you can do:

```
sed 's/},,$/},/g' yourfile.txt
```

`$` is an assurance that it's matching end of line's commas.  `-i` option allows you to edit file in place.

```
sed -i 's/},,$/},/g' yourfile.txt
```